# JBoss Fuse 6.3.0 CXF reference tutorial with JBoss Deveoper Studio latest versions such as 9.* or 10.*

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, cxf, jboss-developer-studio

I'm searching some tutorial to learn step by step guide to learn about CXF web service expose tutorial but could not able to find proper guide line. Please can some one share good reference document to learn about this, (Specially if it is use JBoss Developer studio latest version 9.* or 10.*)

I was able to find reference documents which explain how to run Quick start sample projects from taking the code from Git repository and show how to run that specific project but could not able to find some kind of resource which explain CXF web service expose example from the scratch.

( I noticed that latest JBoss Developer Studio has new set of components to use in camel routing xml file as well, appreciate if you can provide some guide about that one as well. )

Really appreciate your thoughts and guide to learn about this technology.

Comment: What is the part where you get some trouble ? For example if you use SOAP you can check CXF doc : http://cxf.apache.org/docs/a-simple-jax-ws-service.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you may need to first go through with the [RedHat guide line](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Developing_RESTful_Web_Services/files/RESTIntro.html) before you start any other tutorial. Then you can go through any other preferred tutorial you like. I believe first tutorial is what you are looking for which provides step by step guide. Others are some of CXF tutorial links which will provide basic details regarding CXF web service development. Those examples can be used to deploy to JBoss Fuse as well.

01)**http://nirmalbalasooriya.blogspot.sg/2016/11/create-simple-web-service-using-cxf-and.html**

02) http://wei-meilin.blogspot.sg/2014/12/jboss-fuse-implementing-webservice-with_29.html

03)https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jboss_fuse/jboss_fuse_apache_cxf.htm

04)http://www.mastertheintegration.com/jboss-server/web-services-and-jboss-fuse/orchestrate-jax-ws-web-services-with-jboss-fuse.html

05)https://tackletheboss.com/2014/08/11/developing-web-service-proxy-with-jboss-fuse/

Following link provide good background about how the different mappings in previous and latest JBoss Developer studio. It contains reference to some video tutorials as well.

http://wei-meilin.blogspot.sg/2016/10/red-hat-jboss-fusea-mq-fuse-and-mq.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use Jboss developer integration stack(http://tools.jboss.org/downloads/devstudio_is/) to create a CXF maven project.

Follow the guide from redhat.
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Getting_Started/files/Develop-CreateWS.html